# Data structure/aglorithm for strings to see if there exists two strings you can concatenate to get a target?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, strings

I want to come up with an arbitrary string, and feed it into my program to see if there exists two strings that I can concatenate to get the target string. What kind of data structure and algorithm would be good for this? I'm thinking a sorted array would be good, and then walk down the list, binary searching for the suffix/prefix needed. That would be O of NlogN I think.

Comment: By "add to get the target string", do you mean concatenation?  Or possibly some kind of character arithmetic?  It's a little unclear what you're asking about here, and whether it is really within the bounds of this particular community.

Comment: What *data* is this *data* structure needed for? Is there some sort of dictionary/database of words you're allowed to use for the proposed concatenation? Is this a *one time* query or will you be querying this program many times? Depending on if it's the latter or the former, some data structures and algorithms may be better than others.

Comment: @Choirbean It seems fairly clearly on-topic, to me.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Glad to hear it. I really didn't understand what he was asking, and I thought it might be SO-style programming help.

Answer (score 1):

Store the strings in a trie.  Build a second trie that stores the reverse of the strings.  Now you can quickly check whether the target string T is a concatenation of some pair of strings: start walking the first trie, using the left-most characters of T (walking left to right), and simultaneously start walking the second trie, using the right-most characters of T (walking right to left).  By walking the first trie, you find all prefixes of T that are in the dataset; by walking the second trie, you find all suffices of T that are in the dataset; and then you can look for a pair of a prefix and a suffix of the right length to cover all of T (without overlap).

Your approach of storing the strings in sorted order is also reasonable, but you'll need two sorted arrays: one to store the strings; another to store the reverse of the strings.  Given a target string T of length n, for each i, you look up T[1..i] in the first sorted array (using binary search) and look up reverse(T[i+1..n]) in the second sorted array (using binary search).  As an optimization, start each binary search from where the previous search left off (i.e., once you've found T[1..i] in the first sorted array, that helps you find T[1..i+1]; you shouldn't need to start over from scratch.)

So yeah, your idea based on sorted arrays works too, though two tries might be somewhat more efficient.

Comment: I like the two tries approach. Although simultaneously walking them would force the concatenated strings to be ~half the length of the full string, or alternatively requiring that no words in the tries are substrings of other words. With this in mind, I think you could traverse as deep as possible into one trie, let's say $i < n$ steps in. Then traverse $n - i$ steps in the other trie, where the words would "meet". Then you simultaneously backtrack in the first one while going forward in the second one until two "end-of-word" states match up.

Comment: @ryan, it's easier than that -- see edited answer (specifically, last sentence of the 1st paragraph).  You just need to find all prefixes; all suffixes; then for each prefix in the first trie, check whether the corresponding suffix (that consists of the rest of T) is also in the dataset.